# creating users in firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am making an android app and i am new to firebase. I want to create new users in database after user registers with let say email and password.
i set the security rules to :

```
{
  "rules": {
     "users": {
       "$user_id":{
          ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id",
          ".write":"auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id"
       }

     }
  }
}
```

now the problem is when i want to add user object (user profile) in database, i can not do that due to security rules because user is not allowed to write in user node.
By the way ,my database structure is root/users.

How can i add a new user in Node users while the security is not allowing it?

Comment: Your rules allow the user to write to their own node, which seems to be what you want. If your code doesn't work, edit your question to include the [minimal complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As you said the rules allow user to write to their own node, but first i need to create a user node with following code: mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(userData)    the idea is to create a user node in "users", but since the user can not write to users node, then how can i create all my users?

Comment: Keys/paths are automatically created as you write/remove values under them. So your code will already work, even when there is no `/users` node yet. Try it. As long as your `userId` is the UID of the current Firebase Authentication user, the path will be created.